# Automatic table filling with specified numbers and their number of occurence

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, array-formulas

I'm having a hard time trying to find to out how to force Google Spreadsheet to generate a row of numbers that meet certain criteria.

For example:

I have a column "A" with 50 rows. Now I need to fill those rows (or cells since it's just one column) with a set of numbers that consists of:

- "1" - 15 occurences
- "2" - 10 occurences
- "3" - 20 occurences
- "4" - 5 occurences

Numbers of occurences are entered by hand in another cell beyond my column. Modifying occurences would automatically change distribution of numbers in range A1-A50.

Numbers don't have to be sorted, the can be randomly distributed (even better!).

I imagine putting a formula in "A1" that generates numbers in another 50 cells below. Perhaps ARRAYFORMULA would work somehow. Can anyone help with an advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to generate a set of numbers according to a list of frequencies:

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(row(indirect("a1:a"&sum(D:D)))-1,{sumif(row(C:C),"<="&row(C:C),D:D)-D:D,C:C},2))
```

Then if you wanted to randomize them:

```
=ArrayFormula(sort(vlookup(row(indirect("a1:a"&sum(D:D)))-1,{sumif(row(C:C),"<="&row(C:C),D:D)-D:D,C:C},2),randarray(sum(D:D)),1))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I could have made this neater by using Sequence instead of row() and changing the condition in the Sumif to "<" :

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(sequence(sum(D:D),1,0),{sumif(row(C:C),"<"&row(C:C),D:D),C:C},2))
```

and

```
=ArrayFormula(sort(vlookup(sequence(sum(D:D),1,0),{sumif(row(C:C),"<"&row(C:C),D:D),C:C},2),randarray(sum(D:D)),1))
```

Comment: whoah, that's briliat, thank You!

I need to work it out however for better understanding :)

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. Plz see edit which is a bit shorter than original.